# Bash single quotation unknown behavior

Tags: bash, sed

I have read here [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) that single quotes will not allow any kind of interpolation. However I came across a situation where single quotes were actually the only way to interpolate my variable' value. 
For the sake of an example I created a file named 'test_file' containing

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Than in the same directory I created a script whose purpose was to extract parts of this file, I called it test.sh and this is its content:

```
#!/bin/bash
BEGIN=3
END=9

cat test_file | sed -n ''$BEGIN', '$END'p'
```

Now I tried different setups of the last line like:

```
cat test_file | sed -n '${BEGIN}, ${END}p'
cat test_file | sed -n '"${BEGIN}", "${END}"p'
cat test_file | sed -n '"$BEGIN", "$END"p'
```

But none of them worked.
My question is: why does it work that way?

Comment: Why didn't you try double quotes?

Comment: Your last two just have *literal* double quotes passed to `sed`; they don't "reenable" parameter expansion inside single quotes.

Comment: There is no interpolation in your example. `$BEGIN` and `$END` are outside the quotes. They are expanded because of that. The quoted strings are `''` (the empty string), `', '` and `'p'`.

Comment: With awk: `seq 1 10 | awk 'NR>=begin && NR<=end' begin=3 end=9`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quotes of both flavors are a shortcut: they cause the enclosed characters to be treated as if they were each escaped by `\`. The difference between single and double quotes, then, is that double quotes do *not* escape `$` (or following characters which form part of an expansion), allowing parameter and command substitutions to occur (with the results being treated as double-quoted strings as well).

Your first consists of an empty string `''`, followed by an unquoted expansion, then the literal string `,`, the unquoted expansion, and a literal `p`.

Your second is a single literal sting.

Your third adds literal double quotes around the literal strings `${BEGIN}` and `${END}`.

The fourth is similar to the third, but drops the literal `{` and `}`.

The *correct* string is

```
sed -n "$BEGIN, ${END}p"  # sed -n "3, 9p"
```